# typedef struct definition and use in other header

Tags: c++

I have some confusion with how I can use definition from one header with other. Let's say I want to use `Test` type in `classA.cpp`. Should I import `test.h` in the `classA.cpp` file or the header? Seems like forward declaration doesn't work as implemented bellow (I get `incomplete type is not allowed`). This leaves me concluding I have to import `test.h` in `classA.h`. Then in my `main.cpp` only import `classA.h` as otherwise I get error that `_Test Test` is already defined.

**test.h**

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h

typedef struct _Test
{
    double somevalue;
} Test;

#endif
```

**classA.h**

```
#ifndef classA_h
#define classA_h

typedef struct _Test Test;

class classA{
    public:
        Test qtest;
        void somefct();
};

#endif
```

**classA.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"    
#include "classA.h"

void classA::somefct(){
    qtest.somevalue;
    return;
}
```

Comment: In the header file. Because when you include `test.h` in `classA.h`, and then you include `classA.h` into `classA.cpp`, classA.cpp will have access to all the stuff in `test.h`.

Comment: this looks like you were trying to learn C++ from C material. This is not recommended, because C and C++ are two different languages. Assuming the two are the same or one would be a subset of the other leads to confusion and pain

Comment: what i mean is `typedef struct _Test Test;`. In C++ you would write a forward declaration as `struct _Test;` no need to `typedef` a type name. Though identifiers with leading `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved. Technically speaking your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe also look at [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: Just replace `typedef struct _Test Test;` in classA.h with `#include "test.h"` . There is no need for forward decls in this code. Ideally you also jettison the typedef alias in `test.h` and just use `class Test { ... etc. };`

Comment: *as otherwise I get error that `_Test Test` is already defined* – this happens only if you don't include the headers. If you do so it is prevented by the `#ifdef #define #endif``, which is called an include guard – even if you include the header in main.cpp again...

Comment: Side note: You should *always* include all the headers you use in a source directly, assume you need `<vector>`, and you get it included from `<demo.h>`, thus you don't include it on your own – however, a later version of the latter drops `<vector>`, so now your own code breaks as soon as you update the demo library – it won't, if you include `<vector>` on your own instead – right from the start. In your case: If you use `Test` within main.cpp, include the header there even if it is included already indirectly via `classA.h`.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I import test.h in the classA.cpp file or the header?

You should include the definition of `_Test` in the file `classA.h`, because `classA.h` relies on `_Test` being defined.

> This leaves me concluding I have to import test.h in classA.h.

Your conclusion is correct.

> Then in my main.cpp only import classA.h as otherwise I get error that _Test Test is already defined.

You're attempting to treat the symptom rather than its cause. The cause of the issue is that you have two definitions for `Test` in separate headers. The proper solution is to not have two definitions. Simply remove the definition of `Test` in `classA.h` and instead include its definition.

---

`_Test` name is reserved to the language definition. By definiint it, the behaviour of your program will be undefined. Solution: Don't use `_Test` as name of a struct.

Also, the typedef is redundant in C++. You could just name the struct as `Test`.